# Respond to theme change in GTK+ 3

Tags: gtk, themes, gtk3, gtk2, gnome-3

Some applications can respond live to GTK+ theme changes. For example, Thunar, Geany, lxrandr, Hexchat will all update their UI when a theme is changed, for example in lxappearance. These are all GTK+ 2 programs.

On the other hand, evey GTK+ 3 program I have tried so far (including baobab, moserial gucharmap, ghex, pamac, evince, xreader) seems to not be able to reload the theme and requires an application restart.

lxappearance (compiled with `gtk2` on my system) is sending a GTK+ "signal" (not 100% on the terminology here in GTK-land) to cause the application reload:

```c
// src/lxappearance.c line 198
static void reload_all_programs()
{
#if GTK_CHECK_VERSION(3, 0, 0)

/* TODO Port this to something else than gdk_event_send_clientmessage_toall */

#else
    GdkEventClient event;
    event.type = GDK_CLIENT_EVENT;
    event.send_event = TRUE;
    event.window = NULL;

    if( app.use_lxsession )
    {
        event.message_type = gdk_atom_intern_static_string("_LXSESSION");
        event.data.b[0] = 0;    /* LXS_RELOAD */
    }
    else
    {
        /* if( icon_only )
            event.message_type = gdk_atom_intern("_GTK_LOAD_ICONTHEMES", FALSE);
        */
        event.message_type = gdk_atom_intern("_GTK_READ_RCFILES", FALSE);
    }
    event.data_format = 8;
    gdk_event_send_clientmessage_toall((GdkEvent *)&event);
#endif
}
```

The `_GTK_READ_RCFILES` event is what evidently causes a theme update for all programs in GTK+ 2, but GTK+ 3 programs appear insensitive to it.

The `_GTK_READ_RCFILES` approach was also recommended [here](https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=39646) (in Python).

What would be an equivalent in GTK+ 3 and later?

Comment: You should be running `gsd-xsettings` and theme changes via XSettings should just propagate automatically.

Comment: Does that only work with GNOME Shell? I'm using Arch + i3, `gnome-settings-daemon` isn't normally installed, and when I did install it, `gnome-tweak-tool` complains of "Shell not installed or running" and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme <theme>` doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: It should work without gnome but I've not used it in that context personally.